# What are some strategies for achieving a 2' eave overhang?

Tags: framing, roof, structural

I am planning a shed-roof (not gable) workshop and would like to have a 2' rake overhang. I know the standard way to frame this would be do to 16" or 1' and support it with blocking, the rafter tail/ridge, and the plywood sheathing.

[image]

For a longer overhang, that is not sufficient. What strategies can be used to support a 2' overhang without hurting the structural integrity of the last rafter (which needs to remain in-tact since it is cantilevered, as you can see in the design).

Answer (score 2):

Double the second rafter in (first one in is the one over the wall) and instead of blocks supporting an overhang, run 2X from the doubled rafter over the sloped wall and connect to the  overhanging rafter. Fill in with blocks between the cantilevered 2X to close those areas in.

Another way is a take on the same thing, but using 2X4 set flat into notches (lookouts) in the top of the rafter set over the sloped wall. The under side can be filled in with short blocks to carry  finish material under the soffit if you choose.

Comment: I have done both , I have always thought the notched with flat tied into the 2nd rafter felt the strongest , 2’ over hang is common here because we get so much rain.

Answer (score 1):

Use purlins **on top of the rafters.**

At the edges, double up with additional 4 or 6 foot (2 or 3 rafters, since it looks like 2 foot rafter spacing) purlins to better support the hanging rafter (really more of a trim board) and roof load.

Alternatively, angle brackets/supports/braces back to the wall framing. Then it really is a rafter.

[image: Image from Home Depot of a bracket - no endorsement implied]

Vern A. Cular, unlicensed architect, practicing for at least 30,000 years.